# My CPU is not turbo boosting

Tags: amd-processor

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on an Acer E5-551G-T88P with an AMD A10-7300 CPU.

The CPU is advertised as having a max turbo frequency of 3.20Ghz, but if I type `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`

It reports that all four cores are running at 1.9Ghz.

Why isn't my CPU using it's turbo boost functionality?

Answer (score -1):

Turbo Boost might only be achieved using a Windows OEM OS with a certain set of software installed. If you find this software, **DO NOT** install it in wine, as horrid mistakes and/or errors could happen. Otherwise check the BIOS menu and see if the setting is there.

Comment: I checked in the BIOS nut I can't find the Turbo option although the CPU should have Turbo boost. Where should the Turbo boost option be located because it is quite possible that I overlooked it.

Comment: @PatrikPavic Could only be a Windows option with additional software OEM installed. Sorry, AMD is a donkey.